# Google maps Autocomplete mouse click selection won't work

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

I have my GWT TextBox widget, where I add the google maps api Autocomplete. I can see the suggestions there, but I am not able to select anything by mouse clicking. When I hover over items I can see the lines are changing colors. Any ideas what to check or where to look?

my GWT code:

```java
public void setAutocomplete() {
    Element element = text.getElement();
    MapWidget mapWidget = AbstractController.getInstance().getMapWidget();
    LatLng sw = LatLng.newInstance(47.1060978, 11.00138);
    LatLng ne = LatLng.newInstance(47.5904034, 11.9958484);
    LatLngBounds c = LatLngBounds.newInstance(sw, ne);
    initAutocomplete(element, c, mapWidget);
}

public static native void initAutocomplete(Element element, LatLngBounds mybounds, MapWidget mapWidget) /*-{
    var options = {
        types : [ 'geocode' ],
        componentRestrictions : {
            country : 'at'
        },
        bounds : mybounds
    };

    autocomplete = new $wnd.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element,options);
    autocomplete.setBounds(mybounds);
}-*/;
```